# Is $\forall x\exists y \bigl(P(x)\to P(y)\bigr)\to\forall x\exists y\bigl(P(x)\to(y)\bigr)$ logically valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$\forall x\exists y \bigl(P(x)\to P(y)\bigr)\to\forall x\exists y\bigl(P(x)\to(y)\bigr)$$

Here's what I have so far, but I think it's wrong:
$$\begin{align*}
&\neg\Bigl( \forall x\exists y\bigl(P(x)\to P(y)\bigr) \to \forall x\exists y\bigl( P(x)\to (y)\bigr)\Bigr) &&\text{implication}\\
&\neg\forall x\exists y \bigl( P(x)\to P(y)\bigr)\lor \forall x\exists y \bigl( P(x)\to (y)\bigr) &&\text{implication}\\
&\forall x\exists y\bigl( P(x)\to(y)\bigr) \lor \neg\forall x\exists y\bigl( P(x)\to P(y)\bigr) \equiv \text{TRUE} &&\text{negation}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: In the first displayed formula, and the second, and the third, what does $(y)$ mean?  It is certainly non-standard notation, or a typo.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, the P(y) represents a proposition with parameter y, I have no idea what the (y) by itself means, which is part of the problem I'm having.

Comment: Note that $\neg(P\to Q)\equiv P\land \neg Q$. Instead, you have $\neg(P\to Q)\equiv \neg P\lor Q$, which is incorrect. If your second line was meant to be $\neg(\neg P\lor Q)$, then you are missing a negation, and the negation of *that* would be of the form $P\land \neg Q$.